# Quick method to make 2 dimensional sparse arrays from a master data array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, sparse-matrix

I will simplify my problem with an example of what I would like done (the actual data I am working with is massive).

The solution to my problem would be simple if there was a 3 dimensional sparse array object that could be fed the x,y,z coordinates along with the data to be stored. Note that I will have memory issues if I do not use a sparse array. Lets say I have an array:

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
    arr=np.array([1,3,4,5],[0,6,7,8],[1,7,8,7]])
```

The first 3 entries are the x,y,z. Ideally I would want a sparse matrix
that would yield B[1,3,4]=5 and B[0,6,7]=8, etc. Right now I am using a dictionary where the x coordinate is the key. y and z will be the sparse array coordinates. So its something like this:

```
    row=arr[:,1]
    col=arr[:,2]
    data=arr[:,3]
    dic={}
    ### x here goes from only 0 to 1 in this simple example
    for x in range(2):
        bool=arr[:,0][arr[:,0]==x] ####### this step takes too long
        ###### now create sparse matrix for all data with 
        ###### x value equal to the iterator
        dic[x]=coo_matrix((data[bool], (row[bool],     
        col[bool])), shape=(1536, 32768)) ### this part ok
```

So the bool test that I marked down is the step that is taking up 90 percent of the time. This is due to the fact that my array is massive.
Ideally I want to just index my way into everything all at once.

Solutions?

Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach -

```
out_shp = (10,10)  # (1536, 32768) for your actual case
out_dic = {}
for i in np.unique(arr[:,0]):
    RCD = arr[arr[:,0] == i,1:]
    out_dic[i] = coo_matrix((RCD[:,2],(RCD[:,0],RCD[:,1])), shape=out_shp)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [87]: arr
Out[87]: 
array([[1, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 7, 8, 7]])

In [88]: out_dic[0].toarray()
Out[88]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [89]: out_dic[1].toarray()
Out[89]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

Here's another approach that sorts the array based on the first column before going into the loop and simply slices inside the loop. This is a meant as an approach with focus on performance as we would be doing less computations inside the loop as that seems to be the bottleneck. So, we would have another implementation like so -

```
s_arr = arr[arr[:,0].argsort()] # Sorted array
unq,start_idx = np.unique(s_arr[:,0],return_index=1)
stop_idx = np.append(start_idx[1:],arr.shape[0])
out_shp = (10,10)  # (1536, 32768) for your actual case
out_dic = {}
for i,u in enumerate(unq):
    RCD = s_arr[start_idx[i]:stop_idx[i],1:] # Row-col-data
    out_dic[u] = coo_matrix((RCD[:,2],(RCD[:,0],RCD[:,1])), shape=out_shp)
```

Comment: Brilliant how you can slice within a conditional test like that. Thanks so much. Before I close this off I have another version of this code where the

Comment: Brilliant how you can slice within a conditional test like that. Thanks so much. Before I close this off I have another tweak of this code where the x,y,z coordinates and  data arrays are all separate. Such as x=np.array([1,0,1])  y=np.array([3,6,7]) z=np.array([4,7,8]) and data=np.array([5,8,7]). I wonder if this spurs the imagination for quick approaches with the data in this format. I like your alternative solution thank you!

Comment: @Canuck You could collect them as an array with : `arr = np.column_stack((x,y,z,data))` and then proceed with the listed approaches.

Comment: Works but its still slow unfortunately (albeit a bit faster). At least I learned a new trick. The conditional test on this massive array still eats up mucho time. A proper 3 dimensional sparse array would be a great addition to scipy.

Comment: Yes I did that but it still is running slow unfortunately

Comment: Your second solution was killer. 36 seconds to process about 4GB of data. Thanks Div.